# Ionic Native Google Maps getVisibleRegion()

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I’m having a problem using **Ionic Native and Google Maps**. I’m using the `map.getVisibleRegion()` to get the *latLng* of the 4 corners of the screen. My idea is to load only the points within that area, however, after using the code as documented, I’m getting:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property ‘northeast’ of null
>   TypeError: Cannot read property ‘northeast’ of null

```
this.map.getMyLocation()
      .then(
        (location: MyLocation) => {
          this.map.animateCamera({
            target: location.latLng,
            zoom: 17,
            tilt: 0,
            bearing: 150
          });
          // Getting the visible region of the map
          const visibleRegion = this.map.getVisibleRegion();
          this.map.addPolygonSync({
            'points': [
              visibleRegion.northeast,
              {lat: visibleRegion.northeast.lat, lng: visibleRegion.southwest.lng},
              visibleRegion.southwest,
              {lat: visibleRegion.southwest.lat, lng: visibleRegion.northeast.lng}
            ],
            'strokeColor' : 'blue',
            'strokeWidth': 2,
            'fillColor': 'rgba(255,0,0,.5)'
          });
        },
        this.loading.dismiss()
      );
```

Can anybody shine a light?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Need to Subscribe for the `GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY`.